# Invalid configuration object(Webpack). Configuration.module.rules[2].loader should be a non-empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I started the project and configured webpack, but after running command "yarn start" I get the following error:

$ webpack-dev-server --mode=development

[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.module.rules[2] should be one of these:
  ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
  -> A rule.
  Details:

  - configuration.module.rules[2].loader should be a non-empty string.
    -> A loader request.

webpack.config.js:

```js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

const commonConfiguration = require("./webpack/common");

module.exports = (_env, { mode }) => {
  const properlyConfig = require(`./webpack/${mode}`);
  const mergedConfig = merge(commonConfiguration, properlyConfig);

  return mergedConfig;
};
```

common.js:

```js
const path = require("path").resolve;
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: path(__dirname, "..", "src", "index.js"),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash:6].js",
    path: path(__dirname, "..", "build"),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path(__dirname, "..", "public", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
};
```

```js
development.js:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public",
    port: 3000,
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.module\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[local]",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s(a|c)ss|css)$/,
        exclude: /\.module\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        loader: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```js
production.js:

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin({})],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.module\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[local]",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s(a|c)ss|css)$/,
        exclude: /\.module\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        loader: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "style.[contenthash:6].css",
      chunkFilename: "style.[contenthash:6].css",
      publicPath: "./",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: in your /\.(s(a|c)ss|css)$/ rule, did you try to replace 'loader' by 'use' before 'MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader' ?

Comment: @NicolasR I tried it, and it shows the same error :/

Comment: same thing in development.js

Comment: I changed tu 'use' in development.js and now it shows such error:Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'contentBase'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Comment: @Mateusze This is a different error, but you might want to check webpack documentation for this one, the error message is pretty explicit. contentBase is a property of devServer in webpack 4, you might be running webpack 5

Comment: Okay, got it. I changed the 'contentBase' to 'static' and now works fine :). Thank you for the help @NicolasR